# In which parts of the world is it legal for a registered member of one party to run for/hold office as another party?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, any-jurisdiction, politics

I learned that Mazi Melesa Pilip, a registered Democrat since 2012 who campaigned to fill George Santos' vacancy ran as a Republican. I was confused since this would have been impossible in my country. She already holds office as a Republican in Nassau county. Do all states allow this kind of "betrayal"? What countries around the world allows this?

Answer (score 1):

### This is a matter for the parties

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

There is no law preventing a person being a member of multiple political parties simultaneously or sequentially. Some party’s constitutions make it a condition of membership that you be unaffiliated with any other party (e.g Labor) and others don’t (e.g. Liberal). Of course, if you do hold multiple party memberships, none of them are likely to endorse you as a candidate.

Australia runs a Westminster-style government so Members of Parliament are there on their own behalf, as a representative of their electorate (House of Representatives) or State (Senate), not as a representative of a political party. [Defections](https://www.aph.gov.au/About_Parliament/Parliamentary_departments/Parliamentary_Library/FlagPost/2022/September/Recent_parliamentary_defections) of sitting members are rare but they are not illegal.